# Primefaces p:calendar with p:ajax value not updated (one step delay)

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces, seam3

I want to call a bean after a date is selected in a `p:calendar`. In my setup I have a `@Named @ViewScoped` Bean, the class `ObWithDate` is a `@Entity` with a date field *validFrom*.

```
<h:form id="fUser">
  <p:dataTable id="dt" var="cum" value="#{myBean.listObWithDates}">
    <p:column>
      <p:calendar id="cValidFrom" value="#{cum.validFrom}">  
        <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{myBean.update(cum)}"
                update=":fUser:dt"/>  
      </p:calendar>  
    </p:column>
  </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

The good thing is, that the bean method `update(ObWithDate myO)` is called with the correct object each time I select a date. The bad thing is, that `myO.validFrom` does not have the correct value. It's always *one step behind*:

- Field initialized with 2012-01-01
- GUI change to 2012-01-05, bean method debugs to 2012-01-01
- GUI change to 2012-01-15, bean method debugs to 2012-01-05

This issue drives me crazy, I've found several issues with not correctly updated values and also some about `p:calendar`. Most of them suggest using the attribute `selectListener="#{calendarBean.handleDateSelect}"` with a  `handleDateSelect(DateSelectEvent event)` method. But I want to call my method since I want to pass the current instance of the variable.

- Firebug verifies, that the correct updated values are transmitted in a POST request
- I'm using Primefaces 3.2 and JBoss-7.1.1-Final
- Even without the `p:dataTable` and only using `p:calendar` the issue is still the same.
- The *wrong* value of the debug output can be observed for the method-Object `update(ObWithDate myO)` as well for the corresponding entry in `myBean.listObWithDates`.
- `<p:ajax immediate="true" .../>` does not solve this issue.

**Update** MattHandy helped me a lot, the resulting question *How to get the corresponding list item in the ajax call inside the beans method?* is formulated in the followup [JSF p:calendar in p:dataTable: How to get the row of p:ajax dateSelect event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276602).

Comment: Note that `@Named` and `@ViewScoped` don't work together. CDI doesn't know a view scope. Maybe this is not the reason of your concrete problem but may cause undesired behavior now or later.

Comment: @MattHandy: I'm using Seam which enhances CDI with this scope (http://docs.jboss.org/seam/3/faces/latest/reference/en-US/html/scopes.html#viewscoped), this works like a charm on several pages. It's _one step behind_, not _one day behind_. I update the question to clarify this.

Comment: This must be a lifecycle issue. The method setter is called _before_ the listener executes. And the listener sets the value back to the previous value.

Comment: Yes, but how to solve it? I also tried `p:ajax immediate="true"`without success.

Comment: I had similar issue wtih `datatable` and `calendar` - used for filtering. Try to add `widgetVar` to your `datatable` and call ajax like this : `<p:ajax event="dateSelect" update=":frmTable:idTable" oncomplete="tableWidgetVar.filter()"/>` . Although I've updated the table with `update` I needed to force update once more - mentioned lifecycle problem. IMO you have to force update once more too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely a lifecycle issue. The setter for your field is called *before* your listener executes. You should not use the listener to set your value.

The el expression on your listener is evaluated at render response phase of the *previous* request thus it holds the `cum` value "one step behind".

You should update your custom object from the setter of the calendar's date value.

Comment: If I understand you correct I should not use `myBean.update(cum)` but only `myBean.update`. By doing this I still expect that the `cum` in `listObWithDates` is set during the ajax request and I have actual values in the beans `update()` method. But there are the _old_ ones, too.

Comment: For a better understanding: What is your update method actually doing? Why do you need to call it?

Comment: The update method should directly update the changed date value in the database.

Comment: Then you should set the date value with the setter (will automatically be set with ajax) and only persist/merge the (already set) data in the listener.

Comment: The listener is now only a `public void update()`. The problem is still, that the correct value is not "already set" while inside this method. (See my first comment to your answer)

Comment: It would be available in `event` if you use a select listener as described in your question with `handleDateSelect(DateSelectEvent event)`. Or is the concrete problem that you don't know the datatable row where the listener was called from?

Comment: Yes, I think that's the reason why I tried it to pass the object itself to the listener.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue today morning. Found that primefaces have removed the DateSelectEvent from Primefaces 3.5 . Hence had to remove the ajax event call from my calendar object. Instead retrieving the value using get..(). Please find the discussion for the same in this link below.
http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=27590