# JSF p:calendar in p:dataTable: How to get the row of p:ajax dateSelect event

Tags: java, ajax, jsf-2, primefaces

In my setup I have a `@Named` Bean, the class `ObWithDate` is a `@Entity` with a date field *validFrom*. Objects of this class are in a `List<ObWithDate>` of the bean. I want to update the `ObWithDate` immediately if a user changes a date. The `p:dataTable` thus is showing several `p:calendar` components:

[image]

```
<h:form id="fUser">
<p:dataTable id="dt" var="i" value="#{myBean.list}">
  <p:column>
    <p:calendar id="cValidFrom" value="#{i.validFrom}">  
      <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{myBean.up}" update=":fUser:dt"/>  
    </p:calendar>                
  </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

The code of the bean:

```
public void up(DateSelectEvent event)
{
  logger.info("DateSelectEvent "+event.getDate());
  // How to get the corresponding ObWithDate?
}
```

This is a subsequent question of [Primefaces p:calendar with p:ajax value not updated (one step delay)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175371) but now targeting the concrete issue: *How to get the corresponding list item in the ajax call inside the beans method?*

Comment: it might be the direction (migth be not :)) somethign like that  UIComponent ui =  (UIComponent) event.getSource(); ui.getParent().findComponent( .... place a break point and try some in the "watch" of the eclipse...

Comment: @Daniel please add this as an answer, at least this is a workaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could resolve `#{i}` (terrible variable name by the way) programmatically.

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ObWithDate obWithDate = (ObWithDate) context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{i}", ObWithDate.class);
// ...
```

An alternative is to use `DataModel` as value of the `<p:dataTable>` so that you can use `DataModel#getRowData()`.

```
private transient DataModel<ObWithDate> model;

private DataModel<ObWithDate> getModel() {
    if (model == null) {
        model = new ListDataModel<ObWithDate>(list);
    }
    return model;
}
```

so that you can get it in the listener method as follows

```
ObWithDate obWithDate = model.getRowData();
// ...
```

#### See also:

- [How can I pass selected row to commandLink inside dataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994458/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-commandlink-inside-a-datatable/4994833#4994833)

Comment: Indeed, `#{i}` is terrible, but only used for the shortened example for SOF ;-) Although I don't exactly understand _why_, it's working. Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 1):

> @Daniel please add this as an answer, at least this is a workaround

adding :)

It might be the direction (migth be not :)) somethign like that

```
UIComponent ui = (UIComponent) event.getSource(); 
ui.getParent().findComponent( ....
```

place a break point and try some in the "watch" of the eclipse...

Comment: Although BalusC provided a more elegant way, it's possible to get the row index of `ui.getParent().getId()` with this solution.